# What does this error mean? "expected identifier or '('"

Tags: c

I'm new to coding and I don't know what to do with this.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int get_positive_int(void);

int main(void)
{
    int i = get_positive_int();
    printf("%i\n", i);
}

int get_positive_int(void)
{
    int n;
    do
    {
        n = get_int("Height: ");
    }
    while (n > 8 || n < 1);
    return n; 
}


for (int i = 1; i < 9; i++)
    {
        printf("%i#\n");
    }
```

This is what I got:

```
$ make mario
clang -fsanitize=signed-integer-overflow -fsanitize=undefined -ggdb3 -O0 -std=c11 -Wall -Werror -Wextra -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-variable -Wshadow    mario.c  -lcrypt -lcs50 -lm -o mario
mario.c:24:1: error: expected identifier or '('
for (int i = 1; i < 9; i++)
^
1 error generated.
<builtin>: recipe for target 'mario' failed
make: *** [mario] Error 1
```

Comment: You need to read the books.

Comment: @plop : for-loop is defined outside the function. scope is missing

Comment: @plop     What is your input and expect answer.

Comment: @Srilakshmikanthan if the program does not compile, it's not really important to know the input and expected output.

Comment: @Gerhardh      i agree with you but if OP post the input and output it is easy to give some solution and correct the code, so why is asked that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you come from a script language background.
In C, all executed code (in contrast to declarations, prototypes, ...) has to be inside a function. It will also only be executed if the funciton is called.

Only `main()` is called automatically. Everything else has to be in functions which get called (indirectly) from there. (Skipping the discussion of interrrupts and other root context constructs...)

You do have a `main()` already.
Do you think that your goal can be achieved by moving the problematic code into that?

If not you have to plan which function contains that code and how/when it will be called.